# Capybara fill_in with xpath

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, xpath, rspec, capybara

I have multiple input fields with one id `specification`, but they have different attributes. I can find them just fine, but am having trouble figuring out how to use the `fill_in` with the `find` appropriately. Currently I have:

```
find('//input[@id="specification"][@data-number="1"]').fill_in with: "This first sleeping bag should be 0 degrees F"

Error-- Capybara::Webkit::InvalidResponseError:SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first is that `fill_in` will look for a text field within the element returned by `find`. Basically you are asking Capybara to find something like:

```
<input id="specification" data-number="1">
  <input type="text">
</input>
```

This is unlikely to exist.

Given that you have already found the text field using `find`, you want to use the [`set`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Element#set-instance_method) method to input it:

```
find('//input[@id="specification"][@data-number="1"]').set("This first sleeping bag should be 0 degrees F")
```

Assuming you have not changed the default_selector to :xpath, the above will still fail due to the expression not being a valid CSS-selector. You need to also tell Capybara that an :xpath locator is being used:

```
find(:xpath, '//input[@id="specification"][@data-number="1"]').set("This first sleeping bag should be 0 degrees F")
```

Comment: I totally forgot to mention that I tried this, and tried it again just now for good measure, I still get the same error `Capybara::Webkit::InvalidResponseError:SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12`

Comment: Is your Capybara.default_selector set to :xpath? The default is :css.

Comment: it's not, but this still doesn't work: `find(:xpath, '//*[id="specification"][@data-number="1"]').set("This first sleeping bag should be 0 degrees F")`, it gives me error `Capybara::ElementNotFound:Unable to find xpath "//*[id=\"specification\"][@data-number=\"1\"]"`

Comment: The attempt in the previous comment is failing because of the typo `[id="specification"]`. It is missing the @ - ie should be `[@id="specification"]`

Comment: omg... how could i be so stupid, ok great that worked thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's not valid HTML to have multiple elements with the same id. You should start by changing that.